# Computed property throws an error although working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a this code that fetches data from a remote server and i have placed it on mounted

```
var get_one = 'https://api.example.com/rb.php';           
  axios.get(get_one)
            .then(response => {   
               // console.log(response.data);
                var data = response.data;
                    this.roomsData = data;
                    this.room_name = response.data.room_name;
                this.roomsData.room_photos = response.data.room_photos;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            });
```

when i refresh the page and `{{roomsData.room_photos}}` looks like this

```
[ { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaaaefd.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaa9dc2.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aab1252.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aab147a.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aab0226.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaaf92b.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaec480.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab3a61b.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab432cb.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab00b91.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab02040.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab43f3e.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab3a634.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab4729f.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab47168.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab7af65.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab7dae1.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab8738f.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab86f15.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab8af48.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab95423.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abbbdf9.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abc455e.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abca83e.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abca0a0.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abcfa7a.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abd9d73.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ac09a00.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ac1382f.jpg" } ]
```

This is my computed function

```
computed: {
  image_viewer_data: function () { 
  let vd = this.roomsData.room_photos
  console.log('inside computed',vd)
  
  let modifiedArr = vd.map(function(item){
  let url_parts = item.url.split('/')
  return 'https://api.example.com/uploads' + '/' + url_parts[url_parts.length - 1]
   });
return modifiedArr;
    }
 },
```

which produces data in the following format when i `{{image_viewer_data}}`

```
[ "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aaaaefd.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aaa9dc2.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aab1252.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aab147a.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aab0226.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aaaf92b.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3aaec480.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab3a61b.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab432cb.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab00b91.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab02040.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab43f3e.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab3a634.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab4729f.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab47168.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab7af65.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab7dae1.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab8738f.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab86f15.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab8af48.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ab95423.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3abbbdf9.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3abc455e.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3abca83e.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3abca0a0.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3abcfa7a.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3abd9d73.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ac09a00.jpg", "https://api.example.com/uploads/609cd3ac1382f.jpg" ]
```

This is how i am using my computed function

```
<div class="carousel-item" v-for="(value,index) in image_viewer_data"   >
      <img class="d-block w-100"  :src="value" :id="index" >
 </div>
```

when i refresh the page i get this errors.

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: vd.map is not a function

and

> TypeError: vd.map is not a function

Why is the code simultaneously working and failing at the same time.

Comment: seems like the `vd` is not an array. Post the console log `console.log('inside computed',vd)`

Comment: i think vd is an object not array , so it will work but you ll get the warn (

Comment: It is an array inside computed (29) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]

Comment: I posted the data returned that starts with [ and it actually runs the computed function.

Comment: its type is not and array Object then orelse you wont get the warning .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that warning message means that vd is not an array , thus cannot find map() . and its working because the type of object you have is iterable so it behaved like an array.

try creating a new array instance from it using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) :

```js
let vd = [ { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaaaefd.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaa9dc2.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aab1252.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aab147a.jpg" } ] 

let modifiedArr = Array.from(vd).map(function(item){
          let url_parts = item.url.split('/');
          return 'https://api.example.com/uploads' + '/' + url_parts[url_parts.length - 1];
       });
console.log(modifiedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like the `vd` is not an array while you getting errors. Wondering why? The possible reason, your code is accessing the `vd.map` before the data loads.

So, adding a null check before accessing `vd` will help here. Eg:

```
 let modifiedArr = vd?.map(item=>{
...
...
}) || [];
```

will be a perfect blend here.

In common format,
`let modifiedArr = vd && vd.map() || []`

Comment: if it is accessing it before data loads wont it be empty or null ?